# How can I customize the template used to create lightning web components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

Using VS Code's command palette, I can create a LWC by being prompted for a name. If I enter a name of `myComponent`, I get the requisite files with the JS file having the following:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {}
```

We have a base class providing common features that we want across all of our components, so our new components should always look like this:

```
import BaseComponent from 'c/baseComponent';

export default class DevComp extends BaseComponent {}
```

Is there any way to customize what the SFDX extensions use as their template for the new component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Custom Code Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/sf-dev-env/byotemplate) article appears to explain how to do this. The default LWC template to use as a start point is [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-templates/tree/main/src/templates/lightningcomponent/lwc/default).